# How do I configure the snapshot_users option, in packer, using a user variable

Tags: json, packer, amazon-ebs

I have a packer .json file, that governs the build/provisioning of several different AMI builds.  The different between each AMI is configured by passing a different base-config.json variable set to packer, depending on what's changing (for example, I have a base_config-us-west-1.json and base_config-us-east-2.json, and select one, to populate the vpc_id, subnet_id & security_group_id fields).

Now I need to build an AMI that uses a kms_key_id for an external account_id, and grant access to the newly created snapshot, to the account_id that owns the key.

If the .json was just for this new AMI, I could easily add `"snapshot_users" : [ "{{user external_account_id}}" ]` to the json and be done with it.  However, even having `"snapshot_users" : [ "" ]` in the .json causes the bake to fail with error "Cannot share snapshot encrypted with default KMS key" problem, if the default kms_key_id is used (as you get with `"kms_key_id": ""`).

Is there any way that I can only insert the `snapshot_users` option to the `builders` section, by some criteria specified to the packer command, or am I stuck having to script using ec2-api-tools to change the permissions on the build ami, after the bake has finished (having multiple complete .json files, to build different AMIs is not an option).

Perhaps, this is also a packer bug, as packer should recognise if the snapsho_users array is either empty, or contains only empty strings, it can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Packer splits variables on `,` into arrays. So you could just define:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "snap_users": ""
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "snapshot_users": "{{user `snap_users`}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Packer documentation:

region_kms_key_ids (map of strings) - a map of regions to copy the ami to, along with the custom kms key id (alias or arn) to use for encryption for that region. Keys must match the regions provided in ami_regions. If you just want to encrypt using a default ID, you can stick with kms_key_id and ami_regions. If you want a region to be encrypted with that region's default key ID, you can use an empty string "" instead of a key id in this map. (e.g. "us-east-1": "") **However, you cannot use default key IDs if you are using this in conjunction with snapshot_users -- in that situation you must use custom keys.** For valid formats see KmsKeyId in the AWS API docs - CopyImage.